Zookeeper fails to start in Windows 10
After doing then the necessary setup for Kafka in Windows 10 as a single node setup, I am trying to start Zookepeer using the command as explained in Prashant Pandey's tutorial but I continue to get this error. Has anyone tried doing this:
'C:\Kafka\confluent-community-7.6.1\confluent-7.6.1>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\etc\zookeeper\kafka\zookeeper.properties
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain'
I have tried it in a slighly different way as I read on the internet by using confluent CLI but there also I keep getting the error below related to openprocess().
'C:\Users\Admin>confluent local services start
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only, NOT for production usage. See more: https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html
As of Confluent Platform 8.0, Java 8 will no longer be supported.
Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\confluent.409078
Error: OpenProcess: The parameter is incorrect.'
Have got stuck in kafka setup and tutorial because of this. Can anyone suggest the way out?
Tried doing the zookeeper start using windows command line by executing the zookeeper-server-start.bat as well as local services start but none are working.

You could use Kraft mode, then you don't need Zookeeper. Or use Docker or WSL2. Then windows doesn't matter as much
